# Why can I not use SetLength in a function which receives an array parameter?

Tags: delphi, parameters

I am trying to use the following function to set the length of a dynamic array which is a var param.
There is only  an error when I try to compile the code:

[dcc64 Error] lolcode.dpr(138): E2008 Incompatible Types

```
function execute(var command : array of string) : Boolean;
begin
  // Do something
  SetLength(command,0);
end;
```

Comment: Since this site is in English it would make it easier for most people to answer your question if you were able to post the English translation of your error message - I assume it would be "Incompatible Token"?

Comment: @RobV: "Incompatible types", perhaps in German or Dutch.

Comment: Yes, sorry. But in this case, the English translation is not that much different. Incompatible Types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define a type

```
type
  TStringArray = array of string;
```

and you can do

```
function Execute(var StringArray: TStringArray): boolean;
begin
  // Do something
  SetLength(StringArray, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Don't forget the `var` for the parameter, or the caller won't see the changes.

Comment: @Marco Alka If this solved your problem don't forget to accept this as the answer (click the tick mark under the vote count)

Comment: yeah, I know ;)
But I have to wait some more minutes.

Answer (score 18):

You are suffering from a common and fundamental mis-understanding of array parameters. What you have here:

```
function execute(var command: array of string): Boolean;
```

is not in fact a [*dynamic array*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays). It is an [*open array parameter*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Open_Array_Parameters).

Now, you can pass a dynamic array as a parameter to a function that receives an open array. But you cannot modify the length of the dynamic array. You can only modify its elements.

If you need to modify the length of the dynamic array, the procedure must receive a dynamic array. In modern Delphi the idiomatic way to write that is:

```
function execute(var command: TArray<string>): Boolean;
```

If you are using an older version of Delphi that does not support generic arrays then you need to declare a type for the parameter:

```
type
  TStringArray = array of string;
....
function execute(var command: TStringArray): Boolean;
```

---

How should you choose whether to use open array or dynamic array parameters? In my opinion you should always use open arrays if possible to do so. And if not possible, then use dynamic arrays as a final resort. The reason being a function with an open array parameter is more general than one with a dynamic array parameter. For example, you can pass a constant sized array as an open array parameter, but not if the function receives a dynamic array.

Comment: thank you for your clarification. This is really interesting!

Comment: @MarcoAlka Whilst Andreas gave you a solution, I've attempted to explain what's going on. Have a read of the documentation links I included. Since you are using modern Delphi you can use generic arrays and you should. They have the best type compatibility properties. I really wanted to make sure that you don't conclude that open arrays are to be avoided. I always use them is possible because they are the most generic array parameter in the language.