# Delphi SetLength for array of Integer

Tags: delphi

I want to write a procedure that appends to an array of Integer, but Delphi IDE gives me compile-time error 'Incompatyble types'. This is my code :

```
procedure appendToIntegerArray(var intArr : array of Integer; valueToAppend : Integer);
var
  counter : Integer;
begin
  counter := Length(intArr);
  SetLength(intArr, counter + 1); // This is where it gives me the compile-time error
  intArr[counter] := valueToAppend;
end;
```

Can anyone help me fix my procedure ?

Comment: Again, I'd like to recommend this article (of mine): [Open array parameters and array of const](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html). Take a look at the section named "Confusion".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not use SetLength in a function which receives an array parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958858/why-can-i-not-use-setlength-in-a-function-which-receives-an-array-parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are facing the error because `SetLength` operates on dynamic arrays and that is not a dynamic array. That is an [open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters).

You'll need to use a dynamic array instead:

```
procedure appendToIntegerArray(var intArr: TArray<Integer>; valueToAppend: Integer);
....
```

---

If you use an older Delphi that does not support generic arrays, you'll need to declare a type for the array:

```
type
  TIntegerArray = array of Integer;

procedure appendToIntegerArray(var intArr: TIntegerArray; valueToAppend: Integer);
....
```

Or you could use the type declared in the RTL, [`TIntegerDynArray`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.TIntegerDynArray). This type is declared in the `Types` unit.

One of the irritations of Delphi's type system is that a type like `TIntegerArray` is not assignment compatible with, say, `TIntegerDynArray` because they are distinct types. That makes it harder than it should be to work with code that uses distinct array types. One of the great benefits of generic arrays is that the rules for type compatibility of generics are a little more forgiving. So, if you can use `TArray<T>`, do so.

---

If you are appending item by item, then I would generally suggest that a list class would be better. In this case you would use `TList<Integer>` and simply call its `Add` method.

Answer (score 5):

It's one of the quirks of Delphi's syntax: declaring an `array of whatever` as a function parameter does not define it as an array like you might think, but as an [open array](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html), a "magic" type that can accept any array of the correct base type.  If you want to use a specific type of array, you need a named type.

This is the sort of thing that the generic `TArray<T>` was designed for.  Make your parameter a `TArray<integer>` if you can.  If not, consider updating to a newer version of Delphi (you're missing out on a whole lot if you're still on an older version!) and in the meantime, declare an array type like so:

```
type
   TMyIntegerArray = array of integer;
```

And use that type as your parameter type, rather than declaring `array of integer` there.

Comment: FWIW, formerly an open array is not a type. It is a syntactical construct.

Comment: I wonder, what's the benefit of parametrized type usage here? Just to avoid the declaration?

Comment: @FreeConsulting: To give a specific, unambiguous type that will always be equal to itself across the entire program.  Array types not being equal to (or assignment-compatible with) exactly equivalent array types is one of the "gotchas" of the Pascal language that's been around since the very beginning, and having to declare a concrete type tends to lead to everyone declaring their own, which causes its own compatibility problems when two different libraries do it.  `TArray<T>` is a way to resolve this problem by declaring it *once* in the `System` unit and then that's all you need.